# What to call someone who contacts you after a while and pretends nothing had happened?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What to call someone who, after you had a quarrel with him and later agreed you wouldn't talk to him again, contacts you after a while pretending as if not had happened before.

Comment: Use his name. My word.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 2):

My first choice would probably be...

> [**nonchalant**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nonchalant) *- coolly unconcerned, indifferent, or unexcited; casual*

...but I'd also be quite likely to refer to such a person as...

> [**blasé**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blas%C3%A9) *- having or showing a lack of excitement in something, especially because it is very familiar*

That second one might be because my stereotypical impression of the situation OP describes is that of a bolshy teenager falling out with a parent (who's been through it all before with older siblings).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**unresentful**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unresentful), [**magnanimous**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/magnanimous), and [**forgiving**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forgiving?s=t).

> *unresentful*: not resentful; not marked by resentment
>
> *magnanimous*: generous in forgiving an insult or injury; free from petty resentment or vindictiveness
>
> *forgiving*: disposed to forgive; indicating forgiveness

*[**forgive and forget**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Forgive+and+forget): to accept and not think about what one has done to you*.

Answer (score -1):

Unapologetic;  manipulative; cowardly; conniving.